# Probability (Coin flip by two people)

Tags: probability, statistics

Two People flip a coin, Each person flips it 50 times, Each person then counts the number of heads, What is the probability they both get the same number of heads?

Answer (score 6):

The same as the probability that player 1's number of heads equals player 2's number of tails -- which again is the probablity that exactly 50 of the 100 flips are heads:
$$ \binom{100}{50} 2^{-100} $$

Using Stirling's approximation, this comes out as approximately $\frac{1}{5\sqrt{2\pi}}\approx 0.0798$, which is surprisingly (to me) large.
(A more precise computation done on computer yields $0.07958923738717876$).

Comment: I don't understand why 40 out of 100 are heads, isn't the percentage supposed to be 50% for each player and for them to have the same number of heads is 25%??

Comment: @NisreenSha: 40 was a typo; it should be 50. I don't know where you get 50% and 25%, but that is _not_ even close to the correct probability. If the two players flip their coins simultaneously, then about 25% of the throws will be heads for both of them -- but that has very little to do with the chance that their _total_ number of heads match.

Comment: Listen I'm going to be honest here, this is a riddle given to us by our math teacher, its more of a teacher student dare, he even told us to feel free to group together, use books, internet, anything we want, saying that no one will be able to help us, he gave us the riddle exactly like this with this typed over it (0.0000) so I'm guessing the answer should be in this form, I tried both 0.0798 and 0.0795 you typed earlier and they didn't work, PLEASE HELP!

Comment: @NisreenSha $0.07958923738717876$ rounded to four decimal places is $0.0796,$ did you try that?